# Scalars in Perl - Can they be exported throughout the script

Tags: linux, perl, scalar, curly-brackets

Not sure how clear my title is, but im new to perl and had no other way to really describe it.
What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
if(condition){
     my $VAR = " ";
}
```

Then later use $VAR somewhere else...

```
if(! $USR){
     my $USR = "$VAR";
}
```

Is there a way to call a scalar that is referenced elsewhere that has been bracketed off?
   {}

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable that is declared inside of scope {} is destroyed outside of scope.
You need to declare variable before. Always use strict and warnings it will save you a lot of time.

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

my $VAR;
my $USR;
if(condition){
     $VAR = " ";
}

if(! $USR){
    $USR = "$VAR";
}
```

Comment: bummer, ok... yeah i use warning and strict. I was just hoping I could pull this little trick off. Anyway, thanks for the input

Comment: @Nick Hatfield, The whole point of using `my` is to specifically disallow that.

Answer (score 0):

In perl, the my variables are lexically scoped, so they can be accessed in that scope:

```
{ 
# start of lexical scope

my $VAR;

# end of lexical scope
}
```

In the above code `$VAR` can only be seen between the opening and closing braces, and after the ending brace `$VAR` no longer exists.